# ColdFusion CFC WSDL Generating Accessors

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsdl, coldfusion-10

I have a super simple component, let's call it sample.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent output="false" accessors="false">
    <cfproperty name="strReturnMessage" type="string"/>
    <cfproperty name="intStatusCode" type="numeric"/>
</cfcomponent>
```

When I view the WSDL for this file by accessing sample.cfc?wsdl on my webserver (ColdFusion 10,0,16,293499 Enterprise), the WSDL has the accessors listed (the automatic get/set for properties) despite the fact I have it set to false.

```
  <wsdl:message name="setIntStatusCodeRequest">

  <wsdl:part name="intStatusCode" type="xsd:double">

  </wsdl:part>

  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="setIntStatusCodeResponse">

  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="getStrReturnMessageResponse">

  <wsdl:part name="getStrReturnMessageReturn" type="xsd:string">

  </wsdl:part>

  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="getStrReturnMessageRequest">

  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="getIntStatusCodeRequest">

  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="getIntStatusCodeResponse">

  <wsdl:part name="getIntStatusCodeReturn" type="xsd:double">

  </wsdl:part>

  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="setStrReturnMessageRequest">

  <wsdl:part name="strReturnMessage" type="xsd:string">

  </wsdl:part>

  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="setStrReturnMessageResponse">

  </wsdl:message>
```

Comment: Which version of CF?

Comment: ColdFusion 10,0,16,293499 Enterprise

Comment: Looks like you should report to https://bugbase.adobe.com

Comment: meanwhile, try adding `setter="false"` and `getter="false"` to the properties?

Comment: That didn't appear to work either.  Thanks for the suggestions.  I'll report the bug.

Comment: Same issue on ColdFusion 11 accessors not honored